# Please confirm that this XMPP code is not threadsafe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, xmpp

I'm reading the source code to the Smack api and the the method XMPPConnection#*disconnect* looks like this:

```
public void disconnect(Presence unavailablePresence) {
    // If not connected, ignore this request.
    if (packetReader == null || packetWriter == null) {
        return;
    }

    shutdown(unavailablePresence);

    if (roster != null) {
        roster.cleanup();
        roster = null;
    }

    wasAuthenticated = false;

    packetWriter.cleanup();
    packetWriter = null;
    packetReader.cleanup();
    packetReader = null;
}
```

In my scenario, I am storing a live XMPPConnection inside a class called Session.
A separate thread of execution will attempt to close my instance of XMPPConnection by calling Session#*shutdown()*. As I see it, I will have to cooperatively tell Session to close the XMPPConnection by acquiring a mutex or something. Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's a [known bug](http://www.igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/SMACK-230).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug. It is inevitable then that I sync externally before calling it. Peace.